# Converting Data Receiving Time (dt) in Unix, UTC format from API Call into traditonal date format using Blazor Server-Side Weather App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, unix-timestamp, data-conversion

Apologies if this has been answered adequately elsewhere, I just can't seem to piece together the solution from the many existing posts regarding unix conversions. I have built a crude Blazor server-side weather forecast app that calls a weather forecast API and returns a seven-day forecast, with each day distinguished by an unix, utc format date (ex:{"dt":1631293200}). I have been able to successfully display the results from the call as follows:

```
 <tbody>
            @foreach (var w in forecast.daily)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@w.dt</td>
                    <td>@w.temp?.min F°</td>
                    <td>@w.temp?.max F°</td>
                    <td>@w.temp?.day F°</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Is there a simple way I can translate that "dt" result into a more recognizable date, like, "Friday, Sept 13th" or "09/13/21", in a Blazor server-side app using C#?

Comment: Please my answer on how you can achieve this

Comment: [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how to convert unix utc to local time.

You can modify accordingly.

The unix timestamp is just how many seconds have passed since the epoch.

```
public static class TimeUtils
{
        public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp )
        {
            // The unix timestamp is how many seconds since the epoch time
            // so just substract
            var epochDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            epochDateTime = epochDateTime .AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
            return dateTime;
        }
}
```

You can then convert that DateTime to any string format you wish

For example

```
myDateTime.ToLongDateString()
```

So if you had for example that method inside a static class called TimeUtils and assuming that the w.dt is a double:

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var w in forecast.daily)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@(TimeUtils.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(w.dt).ToLongDateString())</td>
                    <td>@w.temp?.min F°</td>
                    <td>@w.temp?.max F°</td>
                    <td>@w.temp?.day F°</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

As pointed out by @Alexander Petrov there is also another way using

```
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds
```

Which returns a DateTimeOffset object.  This can also be an alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked like a champ after one minor adjustment in the method (changed the return value from "dateTime" to "epochDateTime").

Comment: @AdamCushing you got it.  If this answers your question please mark as answered. Cheers

Comment: [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov yes i will add to the answer for completeness. Thank you.

Comment: @AdamCushing it might not let you upvote but it might let you mark as answer

Comment: apologies! I think I figured it out, green check-mark, right? Hopefully marked as answered now.